# Robolectric 3.0: How can I work around InflateException "Error inflating class RecyclerView"

Tags: android, robolectric

(**UPDATE:** Robolectric 3.0 final has been released and this should no longer be a problem...)

I've [cloned](https://github.com/glombard/deckard-gradle) the Robolectric deckard-gradle sample and made the following changes:

- changed to robolectric:3.0-SNAPSHOT from Sonateype.
- [added a RecyclerView](https://github.com/glombard/deckard-gradle/commit/1b0571660ab5e728f2b8d54f8dab55e6d510127f) to the deckard.xml layout file.

This results, as expected, in the following exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file /private/tmp/deckard-gradle/build/intermediates/res/debug/layout/deckard.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class RecyclerView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at com.example.activity.DeckardActivity.onCreate(DeckardActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$3.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:241)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:138)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:114)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:309)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:47)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:110)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:121)
    at com.example.activity.DeckardActivityTest.testSomething(DeckardActivityTest.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:167)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.RecyclerView
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.getByteCode(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:166)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:123)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:95)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:48)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    ... 37 more
```

This is of course because Robolectric doesn't support the appcompat-v7 like RecyclerView yet.

However, there must be a work-around to avoid the InflateExceoption? I don't even care for now whether the RecyclerView gets inflated with a ShadowRecyclerView. I just want to avoid the exception in the test *without* hacking my production code like injecting the ID of the layout to use...

I assume this can be fixed by implementing a Shadow RecyclerView but I haven't had success so far.

I'm using Java 1.7.0_60 and the latest versions of Android tools.

Related issues logged on github for Robolectric:

- [Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView #1453](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1453)
- [Robolectric 2.3 failing to create a custom view with custom attributes. #1102](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1102)
- [Lolipop - Unable to test ActionBarActivity (needed for backporting material design) #1332](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1332)
- [Support appcompat-v7 #1446](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1446)

Comment: When is the last time you tried this? I do not have this problem. Post code.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I linked to the code at the top of the question :-) I last tried it in Feb, but I've since switched to Robolectric 2.4 and stopped trying to use it with appcompat-v7 type stuff.

Comment: Since it has been more than a month, I am sure it is safe to switch to the 3.0 snapshot. I have recently update my tests and they run fine. I suggest you try again. There is no way to answer your question if you have not tried since.

Comment: Try using the latest Robolectric 3.0-rc3.

Comment: What is the status of this? Can this be closed? If you use Robolectric 3.0-rc3, you will be fine.

Comment: You're right, this is outdated.

Comment: Robolectric 3.0 release is out now.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Robolectric 3.